# Vue.js 2.0: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: vue-component, vuejs2, vue-loader

I'm making a Vue 2 component. But when I `npm link` it in other project and imported (I'm importing it in a random component doing: `import InputTag from 'vue-input-tag'` ) I'm seeing this:

`Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
(found in component <input-tag>)`

Any ideas? I'm going crazy.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/matiastucci/vue-input-tag/tree/wtf

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should build it and point `main` file in `package.json` to this.

Comment: @imcvampire yeah, that's what I'm doing

Comment: Sorry but I can't see your `dist` folder in your repo so I can't do anything.

Comment: that's because is in the `.gitignore`. Is being generated after `npm run build`

Comment: So it will be ignored by npm when you run `npm publish`

Comment: @imcvampire the component is being exported and imported correctly. The problem is that template/render issue that I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same issue when upgrading an old (v0.11.x) Vue.js app. Vue.js 2.x introduces compiled (render-function) templates. Additionally, these are the new default.

Here's more info from the 2.x docs:
http://vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#Standalone-vs-Runtime-only-Build

In my case, I was using browserify and partialify to include the templates (as strings), so there was no pre-compilation to render function happening.

To fix this, I used [aliasify](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify) to make sure the `vue` requirement was fulfilled with the "Standalone" copy of Vue.js rather than the "Runtime-only" version.

I did the following:

1. `npm install --save-dev aliasify`
2. edited the `package.json` to include this code:

   ```
   "aliasify": {
       "aliases": {
         "vue": "vue/dist/vue.js"
       }
     }
   ```
3. added `-t aliasify` to my `browserify` command, which now reads:

   ```
   browserify -e src/main.js -t aliasify -t partialify -o build/bundle.js
   ```

You can do this with webpack also--and there's info in the Vue.js docs for that.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I already have the alias: https://github.com/matiastucci/vue-input-tag/blob/wtf/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L26 :/